# How To Avoid Density Curve Getting Cut Off In Plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

I am working on an assignment using R and the fitted density curve that is overlaid on the histogram is cut off at it's peak.

Example:

```
x <- rexp(1000, 0.2)
hist(x, prob = TRUE)
lines(density(x), col = "blue", lty = 3, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

I have done a search on the internet for this but didn't find anything addressing this problem.  I have tried playing with the margins, but that doesn't work.  Am I missing something in my code?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question really belongs on SO so will probably end up migrated there. The basic issue is that when you drew the histogram first, the scale is right for the histogram but not for the curve. You need to adjust the scale so that the curve will fit too. Can you compute the height of the highest point on the density curve and then use it in `ylim`?

Comment: A more sophisticated approach would be to recognise that the histogram can sometimes go higher than the peak of the density curve (particularly if your sample size is quite small or your bin width is narrow so the histogram is "spikier"). You could compute the densities that `hist` will use, find the highest, then pick the maximum of the highest histogram density and the highest PDF curve density. If that's too much bother, you might just compute the peak PDF density and add 20% or so to it, and hope that that will do you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Silverfish!

After a bit more digging within R's documentation, I found a way to have the density curve show without the cutoff.  The `density()` function has an argument called `adjust` that allows you to... well... adjust the density curve.  By using a value > 1, I was able to bring things into frame within the graph without distorting the curve itself.

Comment: @Silverfish gives you the best advice about the vertical axis.  In addition, if the process that generates the data always generates non-negative values, than having too much of the nonparametric density to the left of zero might also be an issue.  There are a variety of ways to attempt to correct for this and some are discussed in B. W. Silverman's book Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis (1986).

Comment: Actually, the `adjust` argument may not be the best way to go since it is multiplied by the bandwidth.  However, Peter's response below works very well and solved my problem.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `adjust` just to get things to fit in the window.  That means that the bandwidth is being selected first by a standard criterion (which you can certainly use or not use) but then adjusted so that things fit because of the frame resulting from a histogram.  That would be very hard to justify.  If you're going to do it in a two-step process without performing the programming that @Silverfish or Peter Ellis recommended, then looking at the joint figure and then running it again with `ylim=c(0,0.15)` to see if everything fits would be easier to justify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the simple literal answer to the question.  Make an object to hold the result of your density call and use that to set the ylim of the histogram.

```
x <- rexp(1000, 0.2)
tmp <- density(x)
hist(x, prob = TRUE, ylim = c(0, max(tmp$y)))
lines(tmp, col = "blue", lty = 3, lwd = 2)
```

(should probably go to SO)

Comment: Thank you, sir!  This solved my problem.  I was trying to fit the `ylim` argument into the `hist()` function and then overlaying the density curve but not creating a variable as you did that is the density of x.